# DocuSign carbonCopies

Tags: php, json, docusignapi

I keep getting this error when I add `carbonCopies` to the `recipients` array:

> { "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY", "message": "The request body is
>   missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON
>   object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type
>   'API_REST.Models.v2.carbonCopy[]' because the type requires a JSON
>   array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error
>   either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the
>   deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
>   primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
>   List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute
>   can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON
>   object.\r\nPath 'recipients.carbonCopies.name', line 1, position 274."
>   }

The following is my request.

```
Array
(
    [emailBlurb] => Please click "view documents" to electronically sign your document.
    [emailSubject] =>  - Something Agreement
    [documents] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [documentId] => 1
                    [name] => Merchant Services Agreement.pdf
                )

        )

    [recipients] => Array
        (
            [carbonCopies] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Customer Name
                    [email] => email@domain.com
                    [routingOrder] => 1
                    [recipientId] => 1
                )

            [signers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
```

Comment: I think you'd better try to post your question to `DocuSign` dev. forums to get appropriate support.

Comment: Oh... That's funny because docuSign API Dev Forums are telling people to come here.

Comment: No here is correct, docusign dev forums have been disabled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an extra array declaration after the carbonCopies section.  Since you're using PHP here's what the JSON looks like as well as what that object looks like on a print_r() call.

Correct JSON:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "test@docusign.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "100",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "carbonCopies": [
        {
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "name": "Sally Doe",
            "recipientId": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's what the object looks like on a print_r() call:

```
    [recipients] => Array
    (
        [signers] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [email] => test@docusign.com
                        [name] => John Doe
                        [recipientId] => 1
                        [tabs] => Array
                            (
                                [signHereTabs] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [xPosition] => 100
                                                [yPosition] => 100
                                                [documentId] => 1
                                                [pageNumber] => 1
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [carbonCopies] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [email] => test@gmail.com
                        [name] => Sally Doe
                        [recipientId] => 2
                    )

            )

    )

[status] => sent
```

)